What does `;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)` mean?
When I execute dig example.com, one of the returned line states:
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)

Can you explain the meaning of each of the components in this line?

;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)


(127.0.0.53): the target DNS server for the query was 127.0.0.53;
127.0.0.53#53: the target DNS server was resolved to 127.0.0.53 and contacted on port #53;
(UDP): the name resolution happened via UDP.

Why 127.0.0.53 is picked as the target DNS server for the query is explained down below; but if you tried and switch things up by asking dig to resolve the name using a specific DNS server (specifying a domain name instead of an IP address) via TCP, such as in:
dig @dns.google +tcp askubuntu.com

That would've resulted in:
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(dns.google) (TCP)

Note that 127.0.0.53 is actually your own machine (which can easily be told by the range the address falls in), and what's listening on port #53 is (most likely) systemd-resolved's DNS stub listener.

Here 127.0.0.53 is queried because, as per man dig:

If  no  server  argument  is  provided,  dig  consults  /etc/resolv.conf;  if  an  address  is found there, it queries the nameserver at that address.

And, by default, /etc/resolv.conf contains an entry for 127.0.0.53:
% grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53

